# How to return a null column using NOT IN () in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to return some data using the following query.

```
select * 
from table 
where code_value not in ('44','45','46')
```

This statement return all expected rows except rows with `code_value = null`.

I want to get the `null` columns also.

How can I get that?

Comment: Do you meant `null` row ? Not `null` columns ?

Comment: @YogeshSharma Well, that's a little pedantic. And how is "null row" an improvement? Apparently OP wants rows where the column is null or it is not in the set - which is what your suggestion does.

Answer (score 3):

Use `IS NULL` :

```
WHERE (code_value IS NULL OR code_value not in ('44','45','46'));
```

`NOT IN` will not return records when compared against an unknown value or `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

The direct comparison to `NULL` is the right solution.  But I offer this to illustrate the "inverse" of `IN`.  It is more like:

```
select t.*
from t
except
select t.*
from t
where code_value not in ('44', '45', '46');
```

Than `not in`.  This is not even exact either, because `except` removes duplicates.  But it is logically closer to the inverse.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using `isnull` in conjunction with a default value which doesn't exist in the code_value;

```
select * 
from table 
where isnull(code_value,'<<non existing value>>') not in ('44','45','46')
```